# How to run python script with library inside Kernell terminal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, command-line, terminal

I'm trying to run python script from terminal, but it's giving me error.

I already installed from linux terminal **library sympy** 'pip install sympy'. But still it doesn't work

This error i get when trying to run python script file.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 2, in <module>
    from sympy import symbols, diff
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sympy'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using two versions of Python?

python3.x uses pip3, and python2.x uses pip

1) Install pip3 on your system.

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

2) Install sympy by running

```
pip3 install sympy
```

3) Open python3 shell (run "python3" on your terminal) and import the necessary libraries

```
from sympy import symbols, diff
```

Comment: Yes, im using ubuntu. And as i know ubuntu support python2 and python3 and you can run both of this version from terminal.